# CSS - height is zero of div but already set the height

Tags: html, css, background

I am currently developing a website. I want a background div that has the attributes below:

```
#background {
    background-image: url("../images/background.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And my div is basically `<div id="background"></div>`.

But in my website, the background div shows up with 0 height. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your style :

```
position: absolute;
```

But note that it still depends on the rest of your HTML and CSS. Depending on it, you might prefer

```
position: fixed;
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: it's a very bad idea.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can move on to next parts of the website.

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/d7Zzv/)

css

```
body, html {
    height: 100% /* give height to your body and html */
}
```

Comment: [Don't use kbd for what isn't a user input](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules)

Answer (score 1):

**Hi**.
check this code
html codes:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="back"></div> 
</body>
<html>
```

css codes :

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#back{
    background:black;
    height:100% important;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

you can see test codes on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrafiee91/zZ2g9/)

Comment: You're missing an exclamation point, it's !important if you want to mark precedence for the style.

Answer (score 0):

The 100% you have for width and height is relative to its parent container. If the parent of #background is body you have to make sure that body also has 100% which in turn depends on it's parent html also having a size.

This is the default behaviour. If you want your element to step out of this world you can use:

```
position: absolute;
```

or

```
position: fixed;
```

Guessing that you're trying to use your background div as a full page background this is the solution I'd use:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  // Add your styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using height/width in percentage, make sure you have a container. So you can either:

1) Have a container with a set height - this will make `#background` have the full height of the container.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background"></div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#container{
    height:250px;
}
#background{
    height: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ha8M/)

2) Write content inside your #background element. If you have an empty div with `height:100%`, it will have a 0px height.

```
<div id="background">
    text
</div>
```